# Order by in exists sub query

Tags: sql, oracle, operator-precedence

When I execute below query I give this error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

error hint to *like*.

```
select *
from image img, imageinfo info 
where
   img.i_id = info.i_id and
   (info.i_state like 'delete%' or
    exists (select * from back bk where rownum = 1 order by bk.b_date desc)
   )
```

Comment: Are you sure that the query you posted is what is generating the error?

Comment: Certainly, Oracle just report that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove order by clause from your exists clause

Comment: Thanks, it's work without order statement but I need to order it. Is there any solution?

Comment: Does your table "back" not store the image id that links back to "imageinfo" ? If so, add the join in there.

select *
from image img, imageinfo info 
where
   img.i_id = info.i_id and
   (info.i_state like 'delete%' or
    exists (select * from back bk where bk.i_id = info.i_id)
   )

Comment: Yes, the i_id exists in back table, but every image may be have multiple back record; So I want to select last record related to image.

Comment: The exists statement will just test if any rows exists in the "back" table. If you want to select the row, add it to your main from clause. You can use an outer join to cater for scenarios where there is no row in table "back"